# When will my momma platy give birth?

Tags: fish

Judging from this photo, can anyone tell me when my momma platy is going to give birth? I’ve put her in her own 3 gallon tank because the other male fish in the community tank harass her, and I’m afraid they’re all going to eat the fry as soon as they come out. My momma platy has been hiding near the bottom for a couple of days now. I’m scared she’s stressed, and I’m not sure of what to do. Besides from gauging when she’ll be giving birth, might you be able to provide some tips on what to do once the fry emerge?[image][image]

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange! :) Your question has been marked as a duplicate of another which already has an answer. If the answers on that question don't help you, please edit your question to explain how it is different.